# Named Pipes Binding Working in Windows Service, but BasicHttp Binding Failing

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I am trying to build a windows service hosted WCF service with http and named pipes endpoints. When I have configured it to use named pipes, it is working fine, but when I try to configure it to use http binding it all compiles and installs, but when I try to start the service, it stops immediately, and I can't find an error message in the Event Viewer.

This is my app.config file. The config in comments works, the config without comments doesn't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config
     file must be added to the host's  app.config file. 
     System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="NogginWcf.NogginWcfSvc">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="" name="BasicHttp" bindingName="BasicHttp"
        contract="NogginWcf.INogginWcfSvc" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="HttpMex"
        bindingName="HttpMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <!--<endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="" name="NamedPipes" bindingName="NamedPipes"
        contract="NogginWcf.INogginWcfSvc" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
        binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="NamedPipesMex"
        bindingName="NamedPipesMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <!--<add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/NogginPipesService" />-->
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/NogginHttpService" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

[This MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) demonstrates hosting a http endpoint using a windows service, and I think my config looks correct.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be welcome.

Comment: Just a quick check, are you sure no one else is using port 8000?

Comment: No - but I tried a few different ports. Just checked - nothing is

Comment: Does the account running the Windows service have rights to register the WCF service URL?  It needs to have admin priveleges, I believe.

Comment: I have local admin rights on my machine and am installing the service from an elevated command prompt. I did set the service to a network service as per a different tutorial, that could be an avenue to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was actually to do with the account the service was running under. Having followed a (different) tutorial for running a named pipes endpoint in the windows service, the service was installed running as the NetworkService service account, where it needs to be running under the LocalSystem account to work correctly. Thanks to [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745969/tim) for the suggestion.